# react-router-dom v6: What would be the equivalent to Route's render prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my `App.js` file, I was previously able to render a dynamic route using the following approach:

```
<Route exact path="/episodes/:id" render={(props) => {
    const episodeNumber = props.location.pathname.replace('/episodes/', '');
    return (
        <EpisodeDetails episode={this.state.episodes[episodeNumber]} />
    );
}}/>
```

**EpisodeDetails.js**

```
const EpisodeDetails = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="Episode">
            <h2><span>Episode {props.episode.id}: </span>{props.episode.title}</h2>
            <p>{props.episode.description}</p>
            <audio controls>
                <source src={props.episode.source} type="audio/mp3" />
            </audio>
        </div>
    );
};

export default EpisodeDetails;
```

But as of V6, this approach no longer works. The URL pathname updated correctly (ie, `/episodes/2`), but the component isn't rendered for the path.

What would be the V6 equivalent to what I'm trying to accomplish? The documentation doesn't make this very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's odd you declared a route match param in your v5 code for the episode number and then didn't use it. In `react-router-dom` v6 you can create a wrapper component to "sip" the `id` match param and pass along the specified episode number.

```
const EpisodeWrapper = ({ episodes }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  <EpisodeDetails episode={episodes[id]} />
}
```

...

```
<Route
  path="/episodes/:id"
  element={<EpisodeWrapper episodes={this.state.episodes} />}
/>
```